# How to assert that mocked method calls happen in-order with testify?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

The documentation for `AssertExpectations` says "AssertExpectations asserts that everything specified with On and Return was in fact called as expected. Calls may have occurred in any order."  What if I want to assert that some calls happen in-order?

gomock has `*Call.After(*Call)` for this, but I can't see anything similar in testify. Is there a way, or should I just use gomock?

Answer (score 1):

Testify does not support this feature currently, but it's tracked in this issue https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/741.

Testify's `mock.Mock` object provides access to the ordered calls through the `Calls` property (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Mock), which you could use to build this functionality yourself.

Comment: Update: I opened a PR in the project to add this functionality: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/pull/1082